# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a Block Tridiagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $T$ be the $2 N \times 2 N$ matrix defined by
$$
T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A && B\\
-B && -A^*
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $*$ is entry wise complex conjugation, $A$ is a Hermitian $N \times N$ tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix
$$
A
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 a & \alpha& 0 & \dots & 0\\
 \alpha^* & a & \alpha & \vdots & \vdots\\
 0 & \alpha^* & \ddots  & \ddots & \vdots\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & a & \alpha\\
 0 & \dots & \dots & \alpha^* & a
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
with $a$ real and $\alpha$ in general complex and $B$ is a matrix proportional to the identity
$$
B
=
b 
Id_{N \times N}
$$
where $b$ is just a real number. I want to find the eigenvalues of eigenvectors of $T$. Here's what I have so far.

Finding an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is equivalent to solving the difference equation
$$
D
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{j-1} \\ y_{j-1}
\end{pmatrix}
+
(E-\lambda)
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{j} \\ y_{j}
\end{pmatrix}
+
D
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{j+1} \\ y_{j+1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
with boundary conditions $x_0 = y_0 = x_{N+1} = y_{N+1}$where
$$
D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0 \\
0 & \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
\:\:\:
E = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & -a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
 This can be simply solve by setting $x_j = sin(k j) x, y_j = \sin(k j) y$ with $k = \frac{\pi n}{N+1}$ , $n = {1, \dots, N}$, and (x,y) satisfy
$$
(2 \cos(k)D+(E-\lambda)\big)
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So we have all our eigenvalues and eigenvectors. This really just comes down to the fact that for $\alpha$ real, our block matrices $A$ and $B$ (which is of course just proportional to the identity) commute with each other.\

Now when $\alpha$ is complex, the same procedure as above fails. So what I did next was at least try and find the eigenvalues $\lambda$ first to see if that would help. Note that our the determinant of our matrix $T$ has the nice property that 
$$
\det(T-\lambda) = \det(-(A-\lambda)(A^*+\lambda)+b 
Id_{N \times N} = 0 )
$$
So now we've reduced the problem of finding the eigenvalues to a problem of a finding the zero of the determinant of a $2N \times 2 N$ matrix. Now this matrix is a almost a Toeplitz matrix, so I was wondering if anyone knew if it is possible to find the zeroes of this matrix. Or even better, the eigenvectors of the matrix $T$. Thanks!

Comment: Try finding rank of the matrix.